# this device is not currently online

Tags: xcode7, instruments, allocation, ios9.1

I wanted to use Instruments Version 7.1 (7B91b) to analysis my app. But when I launch the Allocations Instruments, the record button is disabled.I have connected my iPhone device(iPhone 6 plus with iOS version 9.1) and the device can be debugged with Xcode without any problem.
 [image: this device is not currently online]

Is it just Instruments bugs?

Comment: Same happened to me too.
Xcode Version 7.1.1 (7B1005)
iPhone 6 iOS 9.1

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue with my iPhone. After some googling I found this

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16242

that worked for me. Shame it seems it's just another "Turn it off, then on again" problem.

Comment: Did you mean drock sollution.Did you mean drock sollution? I restart my device.and for setup 7. I get the same message( "Enable this device for development?" and message "This will open Xcode and enable this device for development."). When I click open Xcode,I get some error message("Unsupported device specifier option." and message "Please supply only supported device specifier options.")